# CSS Select #shadow-root

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to use CSS to set the `fill` of the bottom right circle to green.

The snippet below successfully colors entire shape to green, but I just want to color part of the shape (just the circle).

```css
    [row="2"] [col="b"] {fill: green;}
```

```html
<svg>

  <defs>
    <symbol id="myShape">
      <polygon points="0,0 40,0 20,20" />
      <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" stroke="black" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <g row="1" translate="transform(0,0)">
    <use col="a" xlink:href="#myShape" x="0" />
    <use col="b" xlink:href="#myShape" x="50" />
  </g>

  <g row="2" transform="translate(0,50)">
    <use col="a" xlink:href="#myShape" x="0" />
    <use col="b" xlink:href="#myShape" x="50" />
  </g>

</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something to always be a specific colour, then set it to be that colour explicitly.

```css
    [row="2"] [col="b"] {fill: green;}
    [row="1"] [col="b"] {fill: blue;}
```

```html
<svg>

  <defs>
    <symbol id="myShape">
      <polygon points="0,0 40,0 20,20" fill="black" />
      <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" stroke="black" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <g row="1" translate="transform(0,0)">
    <use col="a" xlink:href="#myShape" x="0" />
    <use col="b" xlink:href="#myShape" x="50" />
  </g>

  <g row="2" transform="translate(0,50)">
    <use col="a" xlink:href="#myShape" x="0" />
    <use col="b" xlink:href="#myShape" x="50" />
  </g>

</svg>
```